# Where computed properties should be placed?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Where is the correct place to put a computed property (inside a model or controller)?

I have seen examples where computed properties are placed inside a controller and others inside a model. In my application I am using it inside a model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  quantity: DS.attr('number'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  total: function() {
    return this.get('quantity') * this.get('price');
  }.property('@each'),
});
```

I don't know if this is the correct place to put it and what are the implications of having it inside a model or inside a controller.

Comment: Difference of opinion but i like fat models! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the use of the property, is it going to be used all over the application, then it belongs on the model, if it's just used within the context of a single controller, put it on the controller.

additionally in your example your computed property should be defined like so

```
total: function() {
  return this.get('quantity') * this.get('price');
}.property('quantity', 'price'),
```